# ¿Cómo evitar que un control EditText de Android muestre el teclado cuando recibe el foco (sin deshabilitar el control)?

Tags: java, android

Me gustaría saber como puedo evitar que el control `EditText` muestre el teclado cada vez que recibe el foco o el usuario se posiciona sobre el control.

El motivo de ello es que quiero utilizar dicho control para mostrar un diálogo de calendario cada vez que recibe el foco o el usuario se posiciona sobre el control, de modo que el control obtendrá el valor de la fecha (esta última parte ya la tengo implementada).

En principio, según la [documentación de Android](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType), estableciendo el atributo `android:inputType="none"` del campo de tipo `EditText`, se consigue que el texto no sea editable, por lo que el comportamiento esperado es que no se muestre el teclado de [android](/questions/tagged/android). Sin embargo, el teclado sigue apareciendo cada vez que el control recibe el foco o el usuario pulsa sobre el control.

A continuación muestro el código [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) para definir el control:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- Controles --> 

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tiFechaCaducidad"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etFechaCaducidad"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/fechacaducidad"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Buen día, esta pregunta rompe un poco con el funcionamiento del EditText, deshabilitar el teclado virtual cuando se enfoque el control, como pensarias escribir dentro del mismo?

Comment: La idea es abrir un dialogo que contenga un DatePicker tras lo que se rellenaria el control con el valor seleccionado del DatePicker (una fecha formateada)

Comment: ok entendido, he puesto una respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Usted puede tratar de usar esto, espero que ayude. Lo iba a poner como comentario pero era muy largo:

```
TuEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

esto es un método del TextView:

> public void setInputType (tipo int)
>
> Añadido en el nivel 3 de la API Ajuste el tipo de contenido con una
>   constante como se define para InputType. Este se encargará de cambiar
>   el detector de teclas, llamando setKeyListener (KeyListener), para que
>   coincida con el tipo de contenido determinado. **Si el tipo de contenido
>   determinado es TYPE_NULL luego un teclado en pantalla no se mostrará
>   para esta vista de texto**. Tenga en cuenta que el número máximo de
>   líneas mostradas (ver setMaxLines (int)) se modificará si cambia el
>   TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE bandera del tipo de entrada.

Comment: Vaya parece que de este modo si que funciona. Gracias!

Comment: @hecnabae me alegro que te ayudara en tu proyecto Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Esta sería una forma de realizarlo, consumiendo el evento `onTouch()` :

```
myEditText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      return true; // el evento es consumido. Aquí puedes llamar tu método para abrir tu diálogo.
     }
});
```

Comment: En primer lugar gracias por responder. Esto lo tenia claro, el problema es que abre el diálogo y, a la vez, muestra por detrás el teclado. Mi intención es que no se muestre el teclado.

Answer (score 0):

Coloca en las propiedades del **edit text** lo siguiente:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta a tu pregunta sería asignar el tipo `null` a la entrada de tu `EditText`

```
editText1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Al ingresar el parámetro `null`, el parámetro que recibe el texto y manda automáticamente el teclado de android se desactivaría, quedando sujeto únicamente a la introducción de texto que manejes mediante el código de la pantalla.